# generate GPG-keys on the Macs

Tags: key, gnome, sign, gnupg

Does anyone know any good alternative for GNOME's Seashorse to generate Gpg-keys on the Macs?

(Alternative question would be, how to install Seashorse on the Mac? I've downloaded the package, but after I ran `./configure`, I got an error saying `intltool-update: command not found`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GPGTools is a decent toolset, it has GPG Keychain Access bundled in, which provides a GUI that allows you to create, delete, find, sign, and verify all your keys - https://www.gpgtools.org/

NOTE: I am in no way affiliated with GPGTools

As for compiling GNOME's Seahorse on OSX, that should have been a separate question; but it was asked, so I will answer;

First, you need to setup your build environment.
Out of convenience, I am using macports http://www.macports.org/ to install the dependencies.

`sudo port install intltool gnome-doc-utils gtk2 gconf libgnome-keyring xorg-libsm`

Now we can build Seahorse -

Get the Seahorse source

`wget http://download.gnome.org/sources/seahorse/2.28/seahorse-2.28.1.tar.gz`

Extract the source

`tar -xzf ./seahorse-2.28.1.tar.gz`

Move into the source directory

`cd ./seahorse-2.28.1.tar.gz`

Configure the source with the desired prefix

`./configure --prefix=/usr`

Make the source

`make`

For whatever reason, I had to edit pkcs11/seahorse-pkcs11-operations.c because make was failing with:

`seahorse-pkcs11-operations.c:185: error: too few arguments to function 'gp11_slot_open_session_async'`

So I changed the line at 185 from:

`gp11_slot_open_session_async (slot, CKF_RW_SESSION, self->cancellable,`

To this:

`gp11_slot_open_session_async (slot, CKF_RW_SESSION, NULL, NULL, self->cancellable,`

and then make again if you had to edit that file

`make`

If everything built successfully, install the built application

`sudo make install`

You should now be able to run GNOME Seahorse under OSX.